# Bigrams and ranks of words

Tags: python

I am using this code to get the frequency of bigrams:

```
text1='the cat jumped over the dog in the dog house'
text=text1.split()

counts = defaultdict(int)
for pair in nltk.bigrams(text):
    counts[pair] +=1

for c, pair in ((c, pair) for pair, c in counts.iteritems()):
    print pair, c
```

The output is :

```
('the', 'cat') 1
('dog', 'in') 1
('cat', 'jumped') 1
('jumped', 'over') 1
('in', 'the') 1
('over', 'the') 1
('dog', 'house') 1
('the', 'dog') 2
```

What I need is for the bigrams to be listed, but instead of each word, I need to word's rank to be printed. When I mean "rank" I mean the word with the highest frequency has rank 1, the second has rank 2 ect... Here the ranks are : 1.the 2.dog and the ones with equal frequency are assigned ranks in decreasing order. 3.cat 4.jumped 5.over etc..

eg

```
1 3 1
```

instead of

```
('the', 'cat') 1
```

I believe that to do this I need a dictionary with words and their rank, but I am stuck and don't know how to proceed. What I have is:

```
fd=FreqDist()
ranks=[]
rank=0
for word in text:
    fd.inc(word)
for rank, word in enumerate(fd):
    ranks.append(rank+1)

word_rank = {}
for word in text:
    word_rank[word] = ranks

print ranks
```

Comment: why is `('the', 'cat') 1` => `1 3 1`,? why is `cat` 3? shouldn't it be 2? (`cat` is the 2nd word in your text)

Comment: When I mean "rank" I mean the word with the highest frequency has rank 1, the second has rank 2 ect... Here the ranks are : 1.the 2.dog and the ones with equal frequency are assigned ranks in decreasing order. 3.cat 4.jumped 5.over ect...

Comment: if you have "dog the the dog dog the" would 'dog' be ranked before 'the' because the first 'dog' came before the first 'the'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `counts` has already been created, the following should get the result you want:

```
freq = defaultdict(int)
for word in text:
    freq[word] += 1

ranks = sorted(freq.keys(), key=lambda k: (-freq[k], text.index(k)))
ranks = dict(zip(ranks, range(1, len(ranks)+1)))

for (a, b), count in counts.iteritems():
    print ranks[a], ranks[b], count
```

Output:

```
1 3 1
2 6 1
3 4 1
4 5 1
6 1 1
5 1 1
2 7 1
1 2 2
```

Here are some intermediate values that may help in understanding how it works:

```
>>> dict(freq)
{'house': 1, 'jumped': 1, 'over': 1, 'dog': 2, 'cat': 1, 'in': 1, 'the': 3}
>>> sorted(freq.keys(), key=lambda k: (-freq[k], text.index(k)))
['the', 'dog', 'cat', 'jumped', 'over', 'in', 'house']
>>> dict(zip(ranks, range(1, len(ranks)+1)))
{'house': 7, 'jumped': 4, 'over': 5, 'dog': 2, 'cat': 3, 'in': 6, 'the': 1}
```

Comment: a follow up question : how can I store this generated matrix into a file? thank you!

Comment: There are several questions on [how to write to a file](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=python+write+to+file), if you are still stuck feel free to ask a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

```
text1='the cat jumped over the dog in the dog house'.split(' ')
word_to_rank={}
for i,word in enumerate(text1):
    if word not in word_to_rank:
        word_to_rank[word]=i+1

from collections import Counter
word_to_frequency=Counter(text1)

word_to_tuple={}
for word in word_to_rank:
    word_to_tuple[word]=(-word_to_frequency[word],word_to_rank[word])

tuple_to_word=dict(zip(word_to_tuple.values(),word_to_tuple.keys()))

sorted_by_conditions=sorted(tuple_to_word.keys())

word_to_true_rank={}
for i,_tuple in enumerate(sorted_by_conditions):
    word_to_true_rank[tuple_to_word[_tuple]]=i+1

def fix(pair,c):
    return word_to_true_rank[pair[0]],word_to_true_rank[pair[1]],c

pair=('the', 'cat')
c=1
print fix(pair,c)

pair=('the', 'dog')
c=2
print fix(pair,c)


>>>
(1, 3, 1)
(1, 2, 2)
```